# UWP play ad before the video

Tags: c#, youtube, uwp, ads

I am building an app that has many movies trailer,  and I am looking to support it by adding a video ad just before any video. 
So, how to implement any video ad service,  just like YouTube ads, to run before that videos. 
Note, the app plays videos from the Web as direct links.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Ad Client SDK supports video ads; [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt313191.aspx) has a walkthrough of how to use the Ad SDK to show them. You can manually show an ad before you let the user see the web video.

Windows 10 Anniversary Update also includes a new [`MediaBreak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediabreak.aspx) API specifically for showing video ads during other, longer-form video.